# Cannot read property 'beginTimeSeconds' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

While parsing a `nested json` file, I'm seeing below error.

```
Cannot read property 'beginTimeSeconds' of undefined
```

**Nested Json :**

```
{"facets":[{"total":{"results":[{"count":448}],"beginTimeSeconds":0,"endTimeSeconds":0,"inspectedCount":448},"timeSeries":[{"results":[{"count":38}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491300260,"endTimeSeconds":1491301160,"inspectedCount":38},{"results":[{"count":28}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491301160,"endTimeSeconds":1491302060,"inspectedCount":28},{"results":[{"count":35}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491302060,"endTimeSeconds":1491302960,"inspectedCount":35},{"results":[{"count":34}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491302960,"endTimeSeconds":1491303860,"inspectedCount":34},{"results":[{"count":39}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491303860,"endTimeSeconds":1491304760,"inspectedCount":39},{"results":[{"count":37}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491304760,"endTimeSeconds":1491305660,"inspectedCount":37},{"results":[{"count":36}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491305660,"endTimeSeconds":1491306560,"inspectedCount":36},{"results":[{"count":36}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491306560,"endTimeSeconds":1491307460,"inspectedCount":36},{"results":[{"count":45}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491307460,"endTimeSeconds":1491308360,"inspectedCount":45},{"results":[{"count":38}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491308360,"endTimeSeconds":1491309260,"inspectedCount":38},{"results":[{"count":45}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491309260,"endTimeSeconds":1491310160,"inspectedCount":45},{"results":[{"count":37}],"beginTimeSeconds":1491310160,"endTimeSeconds":1491311060,"inspectedCount":37}],"name":"b20"}]}
```

**Have written below code :**

```
var json = {above--nested--json}
$.each(json.facets, function(i, item) {
            var obj = json.facets[i];
            name = json.facets[i].name;
            console.log(json.facets[0]);
            data.addColumn('string', name);
            $.each(json.facets[i], function(j, item) {
                console.log('Time Series : '+json.facets[i]);
                curtime = json.facets[i].timeSeries[j].beginTimeSeconds;
                curcount = json.facets[i].timeSeries[j].inspectedCount;
                curname = name + ' : ' + curcount;
            });

            data.addRows([ [ new Date(curtime * 1000), curname ] ]);
        });
```

When I print, `console.log(json.facets[0].timeSeries[0].beginTimeSeconds)` it is printing, however `json.facets[i].timeSeries[j].beginTimeSeconds` doesn't work at all.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with JSON here? Is the variable `json` a string? JSON != JS object

Comment: Edited question now. Here json is a variable holding nested json string. 
Have added the json string to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you're calling `$.each` on various different objects - not arrays. So you seem to expect variables like `j` to hold integers containing the index of the element, when in fact they hold the `key` of the property in the object.

To solve this problem you can simplify the code by using the references to the objects which `$.each` provides you in the handler function parameters, like this:

```
$.each(json.facets, function(i, facet) {
  name = facet.name;
  data.addColumn('string', name);

  $.each(facet.timeSeries, function(j, timeSeries) {
    curtime = timeSeries.beginTimeSeconds;
    curcount = timeSeries.inspectedCount;
    var curname = name + ' : ' + curcount;

    // do something with curname here...
  });

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(curtime * 1000), curname]
  ]);
});
```

```js
var json = {
  "facets": [{
    "total": {
      "results": [{
        "count": 448
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 0,
      "endTimeSeconds": 0,
      "inspectedCount": 448
    },
    "timeSeries": [{
      "results": [{
        "count": 38
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491300260,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491301160,
      "inspectedCount": 38
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 28
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491301160,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491302060,
      "inspectedCount": 28
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 35
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491302060,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491302960,
      "inspectedCount": 35
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 34
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491302960,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491303860,
      "inspectedCount": 34
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 39
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491303860,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491304760,
      "inspectedCount": 39
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 37
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491304760,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491305660,
      "inspectedCount": 37
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 36
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491305660,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491306560,
      "inspectedCount": 36
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 36
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491306560,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491307460,
      "inspectedCount": 36
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 45
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491307460,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491308360,
      "inspectedCount": 45
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 38
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491308360,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491309260,
      "inspectedCount": 38
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 45
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491309260,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491310160,
      "inspectedCount": 45
    }, {
      "results": [{
        "count": 37
      }],
      "beginTimeSeconds": 1491310160,
      "endTimeSeconds": 1491311060,
      "inspectedCount": 37
    }],
    "name": "b20"
  }]
}

$.each(json.facets, function(i, facet) {
  name = facet.name;
  //data.addColumn('string', name);
  
  $.each(facet.timeSeries, function(j, timeSeries) {
    curtime = timeSeries.beginTimeSeconds;
    curcount = timeSeries.inspectedCount;
    curname = name + ' : ' + curcount;
    console.log(curname);
  });

  /*
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(curtime * 1000), curname]
  ]);
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```